# WordPress Comment post time issue

Tags: wordpress, post, time, comments

I am getting issue with my current WordPress installation.
Whenever anybody posting any comment on a blog, the time is less than 2 hrs of the current time of posting. I have checked the server time and it is showing properly in php and mysql both. But still when each comment posted, the comment_date column of wp_comments table inserted value with 2 hrs subtracted value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.support.wordpress.com/settings/general-settings/

> Timezone is set to Coordinated Universal Time, UTC by default...

Comment: I got the same problem like Thinktank, but my time settings are correct. Wordpress says: "UTC-Time is 19.04.2012 15:20" and "your time is 19.04.2012 17:20" - but when someone posts a comment, it's UTC-Time and not the time I setup (UTC+2). Any suggestions?